# Ubuntu 16 keeps asking for smb password

Tags: smb

I have a problem in Ubuntu 16, trying to connect to my windows shares with smb. I do exactly the same with Ubuntu 15 but it keeps asking for password while in 15 version it connects directly after entering the smb url.

Sometime it pops a window and has the anonymous option, I click it but still then it pops again...

Same problem happening in Kodi as well but only in Ubuntu 16, in 15 just connecting directly.

Is this a known issue? Any solutions?

Comment: Possibly of help: http://serverfault.com/questions/630631/how-to-make-samba-share-to-not-ask-for-password